# Java How can an object reference the class that created it

Tags: java

This information probably exists somewhere but I don't know what keywords to use to find it

So if the main method `foo` of my program creates an object `bar` of another class, how can `bar` reference the methods in `foo`.

```
public class Foo{

    Bar baz = new Bar(); 

    public Foo(){}

    public int getNum(){ 

      return 3; 

   }
}

public class Bar{

    public Bar(){ 

     /*Somehow use getNum*/

    }
}
```

I could probably have `Bar` extend `foo`, or create a `foo` object.

The problem is a `foo` object already exists (the one that created `bar`) and I just don't know how to reference it.

Comment: Pass `Foo` instance into `Bar`. `new Bar(this)` and change `Bar` constructor `public Bar(Foo foo)`.

Comment: Also, what you are doing can cause circular dependency and  if `getNum` depends on some instance variable that is initialized in `Foo`s constructor it will fail when it is called from `Bar`s constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need! Fast, short and simple

Comment: See my second comment. I personally dont recommend using that type of dependency. It is wrong to pass instance of object to another object when the former has not been fully initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects do not know what classes created them<sup>*</sup>, so you need to tell them by passing a reference to the constructor:

```
private final Foo foo;
public Bar(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
...
public class Foo {
    Bar baz = new Bar(this);
    ...
}
```

<sup>*</sup> Objects of inner classes get a reference to their outer object implicitly, but it may not necessarily be the class that created them. The only objects that always get a reference to the creating class are objects of method-local and anonymous classes.

Answer (score 2):

Create `Foo` field in the `Bar` class, then create a constructor for `Bar` that takes `Foo` parameters. Use the constructor to set the instance of your field. Now all you have to do is pass the [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword into  the constructor:

```
public class Foo {  
    Bar baz = new Bar(this);

    public Foo() {
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return 3;
    }
}
public class Bar {
    private Foo parent;

    public Bar(Foo foo) {
        this.parent = foo;
    }
    public Foo getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```